# Change data in zipped file containing multiple files in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, zip, webapi

I have file named for example dummy.zip. Inside it i have two folders, folder A, and folder B. Inside both of them i have two files, inside folder A i have 1.txt and 2.txt, inside folder B i have 3.txt and 4.txt. Tree looks like this:

```
- dummy.zip
-- A
--- 1.txt
--- 2.txt
-- B
--- 3.txt
--- 4.txt
```

In each text file i have number from name of file, for ex: 3.txt have written inside 3.
What the point of this? I need to multiply values inside that files by themselves, save that value inside it, compress again and download. For example 1.txt: 1x1=1, 2.txt: 2x2=4

So at this moment i achive only something like this:

```
public void ZIPFilesCSVToXML(IFormFile file)
    {
      using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
      using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream))
      {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
          if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          {

          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But i have exception at foreachLine:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=The
> inner stream position has changed unexpectedly.
> Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http   Ślad stosu:    w
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ReferenceReadStream.VerifyPosition()    w
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ReferenceReadStream.set_Position(Int64
> value)    w Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ReferenceReadStream.Seek(Int64
> offset, SeekOrigin origin)    w
> System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadCentralDirectory()    w
> System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.get_Entries()    w
> DatabaseConnection.Repository.ConvertRepository.ZIPFilesCSVToXML(IFormFile
> file) w
> C:\ForkRepos\tachotranslations\micro_services\DatabaseConnection\DatabaseConnection\Repository\ConvertRepository.cs:wiersz
> 71    w
> DatabaseConnection.Controllers.ConvertController.ConvertZippedCSVToZippedXML(IFormFile
> file) w
> C:\ForkRepos\tachotranslations\micro_services\DatabaseConnection\DatabaseConnection\Controllers\ConvertController.cs:wiersz
> 54    w
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
> target, Object[] parameters)    w
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    w
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> w
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    w
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()

Before you answer, i know how to upload and download file, i need to know how to do these steps:

- open zip to memory stream
- change values inside
- save zip from memory stream

#Update 1

Okay, i achived how to open and modify data from files, now i need to know how to:

- rename file
- save changed data to file
- make it as one file in zip

Code:

```
public void ZIPFilesXMLToCSV(IFormFile file)
    {
      using (Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream())
      using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream))
      {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries.ToArray())
        {
          
          if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          {
            string converted = StreamXMLToStringCSV(entry.Open());

          }
        }
      }
    }
```

#Update 2

Atm, i stuck with this code:

ConvertRepository:

```
public Stream ZIPFilesXMLToCSV(IFormFile file)
{
  using (Stream oldStream = file.OpenReadStream())
  using (ZipArchive oldArchive = new ZipArchive(oldStream))
  using (Stream newStream = new MemoryStream())   
  using (ZipArchive newArchive = new ZipArchive(newStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
  {
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in oldArchive.Entries.ToArray())
    {
      
      if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".resx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        var fileNameParts = entry.FullName.Split('.');

        string converted = StreamXMLToStringCSV(entry.Open());
        ZipArchiveEntry oldEntry = oldArchive.GetEntry(entry.FullName),
          newEntry = newArchive.CreateEntry(fileNameParts[0] + fileNameParts[1] + ".csv");
        using (Stream oldEntryStream = oldEntry.Open())
        using (Stream newEntryStream = newEntry.Open())
        {
          oldEntryStream.CopyTo(newEntryStream);
        }
        //oldEntry.Delete();
      }
    }
    return newStream;
      }
```

ConvertController

```
[HttpPost("")]
    [Route("zipxmltozipcsv")]
    public IActionResult ConvertZippedCSVToZippedXML(IFormFile file)
    {
      Stream stream = _convertRepository.ZIPFilesXMLToCSV(file);
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
      sw.Write(stream);
      sw.Flush();
      ms.Position = 0;
      return File(ms, "archive/zip", "test.zip");
    }
```

I cant figure out how to finish it

Comment: Probably you are reading content of entry inside 'foreach' loop which changes position in reader. Try 'foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries.ToArray())' - to assure that entry collection will be fetched at once

Comment: @Quercus same error:  System.InvalidOperationException: „The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly.”

Comment: You must not dispose a stream that you return from a method, it's dead. Also, you don't need to create other intermediary memory streams, something like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/6LRySEu5 or you can also directly stream to Response.Body and avoid memory streams completely which is better.

Comment: Use SharpZipLib it should be easiest to manipulate all kind of compressed files and content inside them. https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned @Simon Mourier, you must not put the output stream to the `using` block.

Also, the `leaveOpen` argument of the output ZipArchive must be set to `true`.

By default, ZipArchive closes the stream.

Example:

```
    public static Stream ZIPFilesXMLToCSV(IFormFile file)
    {
       Stream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (ZipArchive inputArchive = new ZipArchive(file.OpenReadStream(), ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        using (ZipArchive outputArchive = new ZipArchive(outputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            var resxEntries = inputArchive
                .Entries
                .Where(entry => string.Equals(".resx", Path.GetExtension(entry.FullName), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .ToArray();

            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry resxEntry in resxEntries)
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry csvEntry = outputArchive.CreateEntry(resxEntry.FullName + ".csv");

                using (Stream csvEntryStream = csvEntry.Open())
                {
                    using (Stream resxEntryStream = resxEntry.Open())
                    {
                        string converted = StreamXMLToStringCSV(resxEntryStream);
                        using (Stream convertedStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(converted)))
                        {
                            convertedStream.CopyTo(csvEntryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        outputStream.Position = 0;
        return outputStream;
    }
```